# Oracle Query error with debugged query

Tags: oracle

While debugging the query, I got error as

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Below is my debugged query

```
SELECT pn.lease_num,
       hz.party_name,
       flt.location_code,
       flt.office flat_no,
       NULL action,
       la.no_of_days,
       NULL remarks,
       flt.location_id flat_id,
       pn.lease_id,
       prop.property_id = '1', bld.location_id building_id = '1309' 
  FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_leases_all la,
       pn_leases_all pn,
       (SELECT *
          FROM pn_locations_all flat
         WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN flat.active_start_date AND flat.active_end_date) bld,
       (SELECT *
          FROM pn_locations_all flat
         WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN flat.active_start_date AND flat.active_end_date) flr,
       (SELECT *
          FROM pn_locations_all flat
         WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN flat.active_start_date AND flat.active_end_date) flt,
       pn_properties_all prop,
       hz_parties hz,
       apps.hz_cust_accounts sc1
 WHERE     la.lease_id = pn.lease_id
       AND pn.location_id = flt.location_id
       AND flt.parent_location_id = flr.location_id
       AND flr.parent_location_id = bld.location_id
       AND bld.property_id = prop.property_id
       AND pn.customer_id = sc1.cust_account_id
       AND sc1.party_id = hz.party_id
       AND la.type_of_booking = 50
```

I dont know what the error is.

**I am using ORACLE**

Comment: please format the query text...

Comment: What do you need to do with `prop.property_id = '1'` and `bld.location_id building_id = '1309' ` ?

Comment: exactly what I spotted and mentioned below...

Comment: @Aleksej: i want to filter my record on that condition

Comment: Than I am removing my answer and leaving alex's one, since mine is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is wrong:

```
prop.property_id = '1', bld.location_id building_id = '1309'
```

It seems that you need to remove it and add some `WHERE` conditions:

```
SELECT pn.lease_num,
       hz.party_name,
       flt.location_code,
       flt.office flat_no,
       NULL action,
       la.no_of_days,
       NULL remarks,
       flt.location_id flat_id,
       pn.lease_id
  FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_leases_all la,
       pn_leases_all pn,
       (SELECT *
          FROM pn_locations_all flat
         WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN flat.active_start_date AND flat.active_end_date) bld,
       (SELECT *
          FROM pn_locations_all flat
         WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN flat.active_start_date AND flat.active_end_date) flr,
       (SELECT *
          FROM pn_locations_all flat
         WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN flat.active_start_date AND flat.active_end_date) flt,
       pn_properties_all prop,
       hz_parties hz,
       apps.hz_cust_accounts sc1
 WHERE     la.lease_id = pn.lease_id
       AND pn.location_id = flt.location_id
       AND flt.parent_location_id = flr.location_id
       AND flr.parent_location_id = bld.location_id
       AND bld.property_id = prop.property_id
       AND pn.customer_id = sc1.cust_account_id
       AND sc1.party_id = hz.party_id
       AND la.type_of_booking = 50
       AND prop.property_id = '1'
       AND bld.location_id = '1309'
```

Comment: getting error as `ORA-00920: invalid relational operator`

Comment: Alex, remove the redundant 'building_id' - he left it twice by mistake in the original...

Comment: Edited as @Veverke suggested (Thanks)

Comment: Your query is working, So my query is dynamic on the basis of property and location. Right ??

Comment: Correct, the same way than the condition on la.type_of_booking